Convert a MultilLineString to LineString with sf
I have a bus route that is a multilinestring. In order to use the route for further analysis, I need to convert the route to a linestring. This is the route (download)
lines <- st_read("/.../cr58.geojson")

mls = st_cast(lines, "LINESTRING")

After running st_cast, I get three LineStrings.
    OBJECTID                       geometry
1        182 LINESTRING (271475.4 866810...
1.1      182 LINESTRING (271475.4 866810...
1.2      182 LINESTRING (269741.2 867887...

Mapview plot:

Although the three linestrings share a point, I cant build one linestring.

@user2856 if you look at the data, these are three LINESTRINGS which seem to connect at a point, and could be made into a single valid LINESTRING. It would come in on the yellow line, go round the loop, and out on the green line. LINESTRINGs may self-intersect. I think the problem in making one LINESTRING is in the direction of the parts, which means they don't form a connected line as they currently are. Reversing some of the LINESTRING parts might get you a single LINESTRING (or there's an sf package function to do all this for you....)

The thing is the linestrings are not in proper order (whatever "proper" means). In this case L1 is the loop, following L2 -- the green line and L3 -- the yellow one from your image. We have to change their order and go down to their coordinates, then recreate the proper linestring:
f <- "https://heibox.uni-heidelberg.de/f/91c231d0167d41d8ae02/?dl=1" |>
  sf::st_read() 

g <- f |>
  sf::st_cast(to = "LINESTRING")

Now there is a check which start/endpoints matches. That's probably can be done automagically in case of real multiline strings (more then 3 I mean)
lwgeom::st_endpoint(g[3, ]) == lwgeom::st_startpoint(g[1, ])
#> Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.1, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
#> [1] TRUE
lwgeom::st_endpoint(g[1, ]) == lwgeom::st_startpoint(g[2, ]) 
#> [1] TRUE

And the final "merge" of linestrings:
df <- sf::st_coordinates(g[3, , ]) |>
  rbind(sf::st_coordinates(g[1, ])) |>
  rbind(sf::st_coordinates(g[2, ])) |>
  as.data.frame()

l <- sfheaders::sf_linestring(df, x = "X", y = "Y") |>
  sf::st_set_crs(value = sf::st_crs(f))

l
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 1 field
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 267847.9 ymin: 8666141 xmax: 299807.5 ymax: 8679614
#> Projected CRS: WGS 84 / UTM zone 18S
#>   id                       geometry
#> 1  1 LINESTRING (269741.2 867887...

mapview::mapview(l)



Created on 2024-10-14 with reprex v2.1.0
My (unsuccessful) attempt based on standard sf_cast(), dplyr::group_by() and dplyr::summarize() doesn't work in this case, ie:
f <- "https://heibox.uni-heidelberg.de/f/91c231d0167d41d8ae02/?dl=1" |>
  sf::st_read() 
#> Reading layer `cr58' from data source 
#>   `https://heibox.uni-heidelberg.de/f/91c231d0167d41d8ae02/?dl=1' 
#>   using driver `GeoJSON'
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 9 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTILINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 267847.9 ymin: 8666141 xmax: 299807.5 ymax: 8679614
#> Projected CRS: WGS 84 / UTM zone 18S

g <- f |>
  sf::st_cast(to = "LINESTRING") |>
  sf::st_make_valid() |>
  sf::st_cast(to = "POINT") |>
  dplyr::summarise() |>
  sf::st_cast(to = "LINESTRING") 

mapview::mapview(g)


Regardless of linestrings orders, substitutions, removing common coordinates etc.
Created on 2024-10-14 with reprex v2.1.0

A shorter construction of l from g would be: l = st_sfc(st_linestring(st_coordinates(g[c(3,1,2),], "LINESTRING")[,1:2]), crs=st_crs(g)) which saves needing sfheaders or a few intermediate objects.

Thank you both. Now I have to go over many MultiLineStrings to proof their geometries, but your answers make it easier.
